# Template::Toolkit variable processing

Tags: perl, templates, toolkit

I'm using TT from perl, and trying to insert into template and process a variable, that itself contains TT directives.

So, in the script I'm writing smth like:

```
$var{descr} = "[% pid = 1; INSERT plink.par %]";
```

And then in TT template (which received \%var):

```
[% BLOCK parsedDescr %]
[% descr %]
[% END %]
<p>[% INCLUDE parsedDescr %]
```

And I'm expecting pid variable being set to "1", and plink.par file inserted.
But instead I get on my html page exactly contents of the variable descr:

```
[% pid = 1; INSERT plink.par %]
```

i.e., this variable stays unprocessed by TT.

How do I make TT process it's contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [eval filter](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html#section_eval_evaltt):

```
<p>[% descr | eval %]
```

From the linked manpage:

> The eval filter evaluates the block as template text, processing any
>   directives embedded within it. This allows template variables to
>   contain template fragments, or for some method to be provided for
>   returning template fragments from an external source such as a
>   database, which can then be processed in the template as required.